# PlaySound functions strange behavior

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing a function in C for play `wav` files. I can play one time the sound, but I want to add a loop option.

I have two modes of work:

> - play from file name
> - play from memory.

In both modes, I cannot play the sound more than twice, after that the function crash.

Note: I solved adding this to the code:

BOOL WINAPI PlaySound(LPCSTR,HMODULE,DWORD);

without it I get the problems.

My Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void play(char * fileName, int repeat);
char* file2vector(char* fileName, long int* size);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        play(argv[1], 5);
    }

}


void play(char * fileName, int repeat)
{
#define SND_SYNC 0
#define SND_ASYNC 1
#define SND_FILENAME 0x20000
#define SND_NODEFAULT 2
#define SND_MEMORY 4
#define SND_NOSTOP 16

    int mode = SND_SYNC | SND_NODEFAULT | SND_NOSTOP;
    char * sound;
    int play = 1;
    int i;

    long int size;
    unsigned char* wavFile = file2vector(fileName, &size);

    if (wavFile == NULL) {
        mode |= SND_FILENAME;
        sound = fileName;
        printf("filename\n");
    }
    else {
        mode |= SND_MEMORY;
        sound = wavFile;
        printf("memory\n");

    }


    if (repeat) {
        play += repeat;
    }

    printf("play %d times\n", play);

    int res;
    for (i = 1; i <= play; ++i) {
        printf("played %i\n", i);
        res = PlaySound(sound, NULL, mode);
        printf("res:%d\n", res);
    }

    PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0);
    free(wavFile);

    printf("ready");


}

char* file2vector(char* fileName, long int* size)
{
    char* vector = NULL;
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    if (NULL == file) {
        *size = 0L;
    }
    else
    {
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
        *size = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

        /* ftell can return -1 on failure */
        if (*size <= 0) {
            *size = 0L;

        }
        else
        {
            vector = (char*)malloc(*size);
            if (NULL != vector) {
                fread(vector, sizeof(char), *size, file);
            }
        }

        fclose(file);
    }

    return vector;     
}
```

when I run this code, for example:

```
pplay.exe c:\windows\media\chimes.wav
```

it prints:

```
memory
play 6 times
played 1
res:1
played 2
res:1
played 4198705
```

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through your loop?

Answer (score 0):

In my computer the code works properly. Even if I play the file more times. 
The output is:

```
C:\Users\avesudra\*****\***\*****\example\bin\Debug>example.exe c:\windows\media\chimes.wav
memory
play 8 times
played 1
res:1
played 2
res:1
played 3
res:1
played 4
res:1
played 5
res:1
played 6
res:1
played 7
res:1
played 8
res:1
ready
```

It's quite odd. If you want, you can download that executable from here to try it and look if works:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iphluu1huzq48vk/example.exe

Comment: Thanks. I'm using tiny c, i add this header and now i compile and runs ok, without it it fails in runtime execution. BOOL WINAPI PlaySound(LPCSTR,HMODULE,DWORD);

Comment: It's curious my code is compiled on gcc, may be by the compiler but I don't know.

Comment: Maybe it was being called with the wrong calling convention previously? The `WINAPI` bit makes a difference.